# Tic Tac Toe Game 2D Array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

My code runs, but it doesn't print out anything in the board. I'm pretty sure i have done a couple of things wrong, and if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.. Thanks for any help!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void drawBoard(char board[][3]);
char checkWinner3by3(char board[][3]);

.
//
// DO NOT MODIFY THE MAIN FUNCTION
//
int main()
{
    // This array of chars represents the game board, and it holds the content
    // of each space. By default all spaces are set to a blank space.
    char board[3][3] = {{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '}};

    // The current player. Because X plays first, initialize to X
    char player = 'X';

    // The winner. either 'X', 'O', or 't' if it's a tie.
    // Or a blank space if the game has not finished.
    char winner = ' ';

    // These variables will hold the number of the row and column selected
    // by the players.
    int row;
    int column;

    // boolean variables used to verify if the move is valid.
    bool is_move;
    bool is_row;
    bool is_column;

    cout<<"************ TIC TAC TOE ************\n";

    // The game loops again and again until the game is over
    while(winner == ' ')
    {
        //set the boolean variables back to false for a new turn.
        is_move = false; 
        is_row = false;
        is_column = false;

        //draw the board.
        drawBoard(board);

        // If the game is not yet over show who`s the next player to move
        cout << "Player ";
        if(player == 'X')
        {
            cout << 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << 2;
        }
        cout << "'s turn:" << endl;

        // Loop until the player selects a valid space for their move
        is_move = false;
        while(!is_move)
        {  
            // Loop until the player selects a valid row
            // Assume the user inputs a valid integer
            is_row = false;
            while(!is_row)
            {
                cout << "Row: ";
                cin >> row;
                if(row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 3)
                {
                    is_row = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << endl << "Invalid row!" << endl;
                }
            } // end of input row loop

            // Loop until the player selects a valid column
            // Assume the user inputs a valid integer
            is_column = false;
            while(!is_column)
            {
                cout << "Column: ";
                cin >> column;
                if(column == 1 || column == 2 || column == 3)
                {
                    is_column = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << endl << "Invalid column!" << endl;
                }
            } // end of input column loop

            // If the space is empty, mark the chosen space and swich players
            if(board[row-1][column-1] == ' ')
            {
                // Mark the space and end the player's turn
                board[row-1][column-1] = player;
                is_move = true;

                // Switch to the other player
                if(player == 'X')
                {
                    player = 'O';
                }
                else
                {
                    player = 'X';
                }
            } // end of marking space and changing players

            // If the space is occupied
            else
            {
                cout<<"The selected space is occupied!" << endl;
                cout << "Select a different space:" << endl << endl;
                drawBoard(board);
            }
        } // end of player's move loop

        cout << endl; // for nice output formatting

        //check if the player won.
        winner = checkWinner3by3(board);

        //If there's a winner
        if(winner == 'X' || winner == 'O')
        {
            drawBoard(board);

            //Display congratulations message
            cout<<"Congratulations! Player ";
            if(winner == 'X')
            {
                cout << 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << 2;
            }
            cout<<" is the winner!"<<endl;
        }
        else if(winner == 'T')
        {
            drawBoard(board);

            //Display a message if it`s tie
            cout << "It's a tie!" << endl;
        }

    } // End of player's turn loop

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


//
// Prints the game board
// We know the board is 3 by 3 so we don't need to have the number of rows as
// a parameter.
//
// WRITE THIS FUNCTION
//
void drawBoard(char board[][3])
{
    char print[][3] = {{' ',' ',' '},
                        {' ',' ',' '},
                        {' ',' ',' '}};

    cout << "     1   2   3" << endl;
    cout << "   +---+---+---+" << endl;

    cout << " 1" << " | " << print[0][0] << " | " << print[0][1] << " | " << print[0][2] << " | " << endl;
    cout << "   +---+---+---+" << endl;

    cout << " 2" << " | " << print[1][0] << " | " << print[1][1] << " | " << print[1][2] << " | " << endl;
    cout << "   +---+---+---+" << endl;

    cout << " 3" << " | " << print[2][0] << " | " << print[2][1] << " | " << print[2][2] << " | " << endl;
    cout << "   +---+---+---+" << endl;

}
//
// Checks the whole board if there is a winner.
// We know the board is 3 by 3 so we don't need to have the number of rows as
// a parameter.
//
// WRITE THIS FUNCTION
//
char checkWinner3by3(char board[][3])
{


    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check rows */
    {
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]==board[i][2])
        {
            return board[i][0];
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check columns */
    {
        if(board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[0][i]==board[2][i]) 
        {
            return board[0][i];
        }
    }
       /* test diagonals */
    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2])
    {
        return board[0][0];
    }

    if(board[0][2]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][0])
    {
       return board[0][2];
    }   

    return ' ';
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, that's why I just need someone to steer me in the right direction. Point out errors I have so I can try and fix them. I'm new to c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Drawboard` doesn't use its `board` argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check rows */
    {
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]==board[i][2])
        {
            return board[i][0];
        }
    }
```

You'll get an error here. If this is a homework assignment try to figure out exactly what the error is yourself.

In addition, I don't see anything in the draw board function that actually lets it use your board array.

Those are the two biggest problems I can see. Good luck on the assignment.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm blind tonight, but what's the problem in this code?

Comment: The integer i was never initialized. I probably should have included a bit more in my quote because the fragment would be valid if `int i` was declared before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
// If the space is occupied
else
{
    cout<<"The selected space is occupied!" << endl;
    cout << "Select a different space:" << endl << endl;
    drawBoard(board);
}
```

This portion is also a problem. based on you're loop it'll run forever.
You need to end the while(!is_move) loop in order to get new input for the player's turn if the space they chose is occupied.